# Creating 3 color dithering image

Tags: python, image-processing, dithering

Hello I am trying to convert an image from full color image to 3 colors dithering image to convert this image

[image]

to this one

[image]

I don't have a clue how to do this, but I assume that I need to first change source image to tri color image (Black - White - Red) then apply dithering on it, so I am not sure how to convert a fully colored image into 3 colors only.

Comment: opencv is for computer vision. it doesn't do dithering. wrong library. if you wanted to implement a dithering algorithm yourself, instead of using a library for it, you could use OpenCV, but you could also just use `imageio` and numpy. OpenCV does nothing special here. -- your assumption is wrong. if you "first change source image to tri color", all information required for dithering would be gone.

Comment: Imagemagick can do dithering. If you need to do it in Python, then use Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither

Comment: that was really enlightening using Imagemagick did exactly what I needed

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer to share your enlightenment with the rest of the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in this post https://learn.adafruit.com/preparing-graphics-for-e-ink-displays/command-line
The answer was to use library like ImageMagick instead of opencv. I can do a dithering on one line command

```
convert input.jpg -dither FloydSteinberg -define dither:diffusion-amount=85% -remap eink-3color.png BMP3:output.bmp
```

the eink-3color.png is this one

[image]

Comment: What is eink-3color.png?

Comment: this is a file that has the colors you want the image to be mapped to, on the link I share it has those files        https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/79736

Comment: That may be, but that also means this answer doesn't help anyone if the site goes down.

Comment: I updated the answer so it would be easier for people later to have this file